# What's the best solution to find distance of an object to camera?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

I have an object with known size and I want to know that's the distance from the camera and camera angle. Is there any way to do this? I have a single source (camera).

Comment: Isn't this a trig. problem given the focal length?

Comment: i've seen ways to obtain focal length but i didn't implement this.